# Rails 4 App with Nginx and Unicorn OK in Development but not in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I setup my server with the help of "How To Deploy Rails Apps Using Unicorn & Nginx on CentOS 6.5" everything is great if I run if I start Unicorn in development but I have a lot of issues if I try to start in production.

I cant get unicorn to start at all if I don't use the absolute "listen" path in my unicorn.rb.
If I do use the absolute path unicorn will start as well as Nginx but when I go to the site I just get the Nginx "502 Bad Gateway" error page.

***CURRENT UNICORN.rb working in Development***

```
working_directory "/var/www/YourAppName"
pid "/var/www/YourAppName/pids/unicorn.pid"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.YourAppName.sock"

stderrpath "/var/www/YourAppName/log/unicornerr.log"
stdoutpath "/dev/null"

worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

***CURRENT nginx default.conf working in Development***

```
upstream YourAppName {
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.YourAppName.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

listen 80;
server_name localhost;

root /root/YourAppName/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @YourAppName;

location @YourAppName {
proxysetheader X-Forwarded-For $proxyaddxforwardedfor;
proxysetheader Host $httphost;
proxyredirect off;
proxy_pass http://YourAppName;
}

errorpage 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
clientmaxbodysize 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: How you run it in production? What is location of your app? It is var/www/YourAppName or root /root/YourAppName/public; ?

Comment: Have you change the `server_name localhost` line?

Comment: I run it in production with this command "unicorn_rails -E PRODUCTION -c config/unicorn.rb -D". My app is in /var/www/. I have not changed server_name localhost. What would I change that to?

Comment: what kind of error do you get? have you made all folders and files accessible on production and all needed files executable?